# How to hide an element on hover out that is not the parent?

Tags: jquery, animation, hover

So for a nav, I am showing a "secondary" div when a certain "nav1" LI is hovered. I would like the div to be hidden when the focus is no longer on the #nav1 LI or the secondary div.  [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eT9G4/1/)

Usually I would just place the "secondary" div inside the #nav1 li. But I can't do so for some logistical reasons.
So I am basically trying to hide the secondary div on hover out only when the mouse is not on top of either #secondary or #nav1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you at all: http://jsfiddle.net/EefAD/3/

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I did switch to mouseleave instead of mouseout though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
$("#secondary").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).slideUp(500);
}​);​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eT9G4/5/)**.

Comment: Yes. It still has the same problem. The secondary should stay visible on hover instead of sliding down.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The secondary div stays visible when you hover over nav1 or secondary.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set a timeout `setTimeout(function, delay)` on hover out callback of first element, and set a flag `true` on hover of second element, and set it back to `false` on hover out. When timeout is done, check if flag is `true`, then user is hovering over second element.